# Minify / Combining all JS files from directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

I am new to `uglify-js`. I want to minify all javascript files from `src/js/` directory to `lib/js/`. Is there any command to minify all js files directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) if you want to automate things like this e.g. as part of your build process.

Answer (score 1):

`cat src/js/*.js | uglifyjs -m -c -o lib/js/min.js`

Comment: You can install [git](http://git-scm.com/) and use the mysys bash. Doing web dev in Windows without a proper bash is painful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James,

It’s working using `grunt-contrib-uglify`.

Here is the code.

```
uglify: {
    compress: {
        files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'src/js',
              src: ['*.js'],
              dest: 'lib/js/',
              ext: '.min.js'
        }]
    }
}
```

It will minify all js to destination separately. I found from [here](http://mostlyweb.in/minification-using-gruntuglify/).